# How to connect to a printer using its IP address in vb.net?

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio, printing

[Here](http://www.marcusnyberg.com/2010/11/17/how-to-install-a-network-printer-with-vb-net-and-wmi/) I found a way to connect to the printer using the server name, and the printer name. However, I'm looking for a way to connect to a printer using its IP address instead. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided looks like it's connecting to a printer *share* if I'm not mistaking- a printer that's installed on another machine and is being shared. In that scenario, the printer doesn't have it's own IP, only the server does.

If you want to use the *server's* IP, you can just put that in place of the host name: `\\10.20.30.40\PrinterShareName`, where `10.20.30.40` is the (example) IP address of the computer where the printer is installed and `PrinterShareName` is the name the printer is being shared under.

Comment: I believe the printers I'm trying to connect to are network configured and only have IP address. (I don't think they're shared from a computer). Do you know if there is a way to check?